# How to get the radians using the accelerometer and gyroscope readings from the flutter sensor package?

Tags: flutter, android-sensors

I'm using the flutter sensor package (as at https://pub.dev/packages/sensors) to get accelerometer and gyroscope readings from a device.  To be honest I have no idea what the returned data means or how it relates to the gyroscope on the device, and the documentation for the package doesn't actually say what those values are.

I'm trying to convert the returned values to a pitch, yaw, and roll in 360 degrees.  I've searched the issues on Github to try to find documentation for the sensors package but I haven't been successful.

Any help would be great :) Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try Using this,

```
_streamSubscriptions =
        accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        double x = event.x, y = event.y, z = event.z;
        double norm_Of_g = math
            .sqrt(event.x * event.x + event.y * event.y + event.z * event.z);
        x = event.x / norm_Of_g;
        y = event.y / norm_Of_g;
        z = event.z / norm_Of_g;

        double xInclination = -(math.asin(x) * (180 / math.pi));
        double yInclination = (math.acos(y) * (180 / math.pi));
        double zInclination = (math.atan(z) * (180 / math.pi));

        String xAngle = "${xInclination.round()}°";
        String yAngle = "${yInclination.round()}°";
        String zAngle = "${zInclination.round()}°";    
      });
    });
```

Hope it Solves the Problem...